# Align to center child DIVs inside parent DIV

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to align a DIV in the middle of the page when the size is less than 768px

I have one parent DIV that contains three different DIVs. So I used media queries and within one display size I added this "**clear:both**" to the **display_type** and **buttons** classes. So in that way each div will be in its own row.

```
<div class="category_header container">
    <div class="products">
        <label class="header t_left">Sorter efter:</label>
        <div class="select t_left">
    </div>
    <div class="display_type">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <span class="button"></span>
        <span class="button"></span>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I tried several ways to align them in the center but they didn't work. Here what the CSS looks like:

```
.container {
    width: 1180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
.category_header {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 0 0 0 25px;
}
.products {
    float: left;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 3.5px 0 0;
}
.products label {
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
}
.display_type {
    float: left;
    width: 350px;
    color: #A1ABB6;
    margin: 12px 0 0;
}
.category_header .buttons {
    float: right;
    width: 427px;
}
```

I tried to add the following to the parent div "category_header" with no luck. I also tried the same to the child divs. I found a lot of solutions on google but noone seems to work. (display: inline-block; text-align: center etc etc)

```
@media screen and (max-width: Number px) and (min-width: Number px) 
{
    .category_header {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: in your media query instead of clear both you need `float:none; margin: auto;` on those classes (to cancel the float otherwise they will stay left aligned)

Comment: I use "clear:both" to have them in a new row. Because in a normal size those DIVs are all in one row.

Comment: float:none will have the same effect, as they are block elements, each will start on a new line.  They are only on the same line because you are floating them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
{
    .display_type, .buttons, .products 
    {
        float:none;
        margin:auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, you are totally right. What I was doing wrong: I used both clear:both AND float: none. And then margin: 0 auto. I guess it messed it up in some way. But now with only the code you provided it works fine! Thanks